# Putting http:// in php, I don't want a comment

Tags: php

I want to put a URL into PHP sentence but in PHP two bars // it is a comment.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Photos (id_user, hyperlink) VALUES ('$id_user', 'http://xxxx')";
```

All after // it is a comment into php and I don't know how can I put a URL into db, because it is necessary to put into PHP.
How can I do this?

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: Your statement should work perfectly well. I don't see the problem.

Comment: hmm.. don't know much php, but // should be fine inside string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `//` separator does not denote a comment in PHP when it is inside a string. (Nor does `/*...*/` or `#`, for that matter.) If your editor is highlighting it as a comment, this is an error in your editor, not in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was the editor. I modified the php through ssh and all after // were comment, but then works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is your editor's issue.